# Exception: Could not find the Soap Header - make sure you have the Soap Header defined under the 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' namespace

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

Im trying to interface PHP with a remote SOAP XML service, which uses industry standard WSE Authentication Headers (UserName token).

PHP's native SOAP Client isn't all that great with some more complicated header options like this.

As an alternate approach, I've used wsdl2phpgenerator on the WSDL file to generate the Class files, etc, however when sending the request the headers are not being included properly. I constantly receive the following message regardless of using the Soap Client directly, or the Class files.

```
ExceptionId e6203b1e-9450-4408-b63b-8ebdbfef169a - Exception: Could not find the Soap Header - make sure you have the Soap Header defined under the 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' namespace
```

In the header, the "CreateDateTime" (Date and time on the client at the time of the call.) is the only required field, plus the Authentication.

I've found an example here of creating the authentication token, however it doesn't seem to make much difference:
https://gist.github.com/Turin86/5569152

So I'm stuck trying to get past the lack of a header regardless of the method I choose.

Have also tried this:

```
$ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope';

//Body of the Soap Header.
$headerbody = array(
    'CreateDateTime' => date('c')
     );


$header = new SoapHeader($ns, 'Header', $headerbody);

$DEXService = new \DSS\DEXService();
$DEXService->__setSoapHeaders(array($header));

$ping = $DEXService->Ping(new \DSS\PingRequest());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
as a configuration option for the SoapClient.